# Contents of variable somehow lost with socat and wall

Tags: shell-script, socat, wall

I'm not sure what is going on or which command causes the unexpected behavior, so I'll post everything I've done:

I have created a script `onreceive.sh` containing:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read INCOMING
wall --nobanner "${INCOMING}.wav"
wall --nobanner "${INCOMING}"
```

Then I ran:

```bsh
socat -u tcp-listen:7777,fork system:./onreceive.sh
```

Then I made a connection (I used PuTTY, but `netcat` probably works as well) to port 7777 and sent one line of text ("asdf").

The output I got is:

```
.wav


asdf
```

What I expected:

```
asdf.wav


asdf
```

Comment: Works fine for me. It may be down to how you connect. I'm not familiar with putty, but  I thought  it was a ssh client.  You may want to add a few `-d` options and maybe `-v` as well to to socat debug. And also possibly use `socat -d -d -d -v - tcp:host:7777` for the client.

Comment: Your input ends with a carriage return.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Ooooh, you mean a CR *without* an LF? That could explain the result, yes.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Yes, that was it, I confirmed it with a longer string. It's probably because `read` strips the LF but keeps the "unknown" CR?